# FIR Filter implementation on Cortex M0

Tags: filter, arm, signal-processing, cortex-m

Is an FIR filter with a bandpass filter with cutoff frequencies 3k and 4k on a Cortex M0 possible? Or does it have insufficient hardware for decent results?

Comment: Yes, it will be possible, but tell us more, for example sampling frequency, how precise samples do you have if you need floating or fixed point, ...

Comment: Fixed point should work. The signals I will be sampling are in the audio range hence a sampling frequency of around 50K would ok.